# How using FirebaseUI to download and display images?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I can not display the image stored in firebase in imageview.

I would like to use FirebaseUI because I think it's easier.

I tried but GlideApp stays in red.

I found this here : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage

Main activity :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("IMG_20190130_160849_731.jpg");

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view2) ;


        GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
                .load(storageReference)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

MyAppGlideModule :

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

and my base storage :
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done clean build after creating MyAppGlideModule?

Comment: @shahzainali How? I didn't create other build.

Comment: You can clean your project doing this

Build > Clean Project

Comment: Yes i have, GlideApp is again red.

Comment: share your build.gradle from app folder.

Comment: Hi, my gradle is here =)

Comment: I am unable to find gradle code or file...

Comment: Suppressed by admin. Wait please